# How to make wheelcollider not stutter when moving on high speed?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, rigidbody

I have a wheelcollider attached on a rigidbody and i move the object using :
"transform.position += transform.forward * speed * input.getkey(keycode.uparrow)"
And when the speed increasing the wheelcollider start stuttering
How to solve it? Do i wrong using the script above? Or something?
Can anyone solve it? thanks

Comment: What did you try to solve the issue? What's your frame rate? Against what does it stutter/what's your surface? Are you mixing forces with this transform modification? You might want to add a link to a youtube video or an animated gif to the question to show us what happens.

Comment: Are you possibly seeing temporal aliasing like happens with video? (The so-called [wagon-wheel effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect)?)

Comment: Aa..... I dont really understand what is mixing forces with transform modification sorry for that i still noob to unity             anyway thanks for the answers  @Alexandre

Comment: And thanks for your answer too @user111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wheel collider is for making movements for wehicle and everything that works with wheels. you should use `WheelCollider.motorTorque`otherwise you get some physics problems like stuttering as you said.

check that your wheels not to make collision with other colliders.

Comment: Thanks for answers... But   Example i made a plane then i use "WheelCollider.motorTorque" The object is moving fine not stutter but....... When i press "w" The plane doesnt fly if i use "transform.position.... Etc" Like above when i press w the plane fly but wheelcollider are start stutter do you know how to solve this thanks